# How to convert integer value to float in json column in MariaDB?

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I need to convert values of `$.fonts_size` json property to float.

Currently there are integer values such as `1` and I need them to become `1.0` to make my app treat them as double.

In this case json like:

```json
{
    "fonts_size": 1
}
```

Should be converted to:

```json
{
    "fonts_size": 1.0
}
```

Is that possible to do within SQL in MariaDB?

I tried solutions like this:

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(
    JSON_SET(
        settings,
        "$.fonts_size",
        CAST(
            JSON_EXTRACT(
                settings,
                "$.fonts_size"
            )
            AS FLOAT
        )
    ),
    '$.fonts_size'
) 
FROM blocks WHERE JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(settings, "$.fonts_size")) = "INTEGER"
```

However this does not make a difference.
Also tried concatenating `".0"` but this results in string instead of double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do it by casting the integer into `DECIMAL` with one digit after the decimal point:

```
SELECT CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(
                settings,
                "$.fonts_size"
       ) AS DECIMAL(5,1)),
JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(settings, "$.fonts_size"))
FROM blocks
WHERE JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(settings, "$.fonts_size")) = "INTEGER"
```

`DECIMAL(5,1)` means a number having 5 digits altogether, with 1 of them to the right of the decimal point. (So, 4 left, 1 right.)